# Printing a returning value

Tags: java

I've just started with Java, and so far been only playing around solving problems online, where you're not supposed to write the whole functional of a program, but only adjust a few lines of code to the already organized code.

However, I'm still struggling to organize my code in a compiling program in IntelliJ Idea, getting confused at,e.g. how methods invocations must be properly written.
Here's what I'm getting stuck with: an example from codingbat.com:

*- Given a string, return a new string made of every other char starting with the first, so "Hello" yields "Hlo".*

I've come up with a solution online, but now I wanna run it in Idea, with main method, with Scanner/BufferedReader input from console etc. Looks like I'm missing something...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Bat
{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = scanner.nextLine();
        printString();
         }

    public String stringBits(String str) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i<str.length();i += 2) {
            result += str.substring(i, i+1);
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static void printString () {
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

I ask your help to solve it out. What to do to make it:

1. Read a word from a console;
2. create a new string;
3. print it out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I have no idea what the answer is doing in the question -- it makes no sense now.

Comment: @mohican93 please do not include the given answer in the question. Just accept the answer that solved your problem by clicking the checkmark on its top left. That way future readers know what to do.

Comment: Engineer, take it easy, I'm the first couple of hours here, and now it's been edited.

Everyone, thanks for support and answers, it helps me out very much. If anyone would like to provide some more links on the discussed topic, I would also appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two alternatives:

- make `stringBits` `static`
- create an instance of the class `Bat` and invoke the member method

---

First solution - easy, not much to change

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bat {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = scanner.nextLine();
        printString(stringBits(str));
    }

    public static String stringBits(String str) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length();i += 2) {
            result += str.substring(i, i + 1);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void printString (String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

---

Second solution - a bit more advances

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bat {

    private String string;

    public Bat(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = scanner.nextLine();

        Bat bat = new Bat(str);
        bat.printStringBits();
    }

    private String stringBits() {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i += 2) {
            result += string.substring(i, i + 1);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void printStringBits() {
        System.out.println(stringBits());
    }
}
```

Comment: luk! 
Thank you very much! The first solution was accepted by compiler, but it did not print out the necessary result, like "result --> rsl", but just printed the input word once again "result - result".
But the 2nd one worked just brilliantly, and I like this one.
I wouldn`t like to ask to go through each step of it and explain it - I`ve got it pretty well, only the part with creating a new Bat instance with (str) as a parameter is still a bit perplexing, so I wanted to ask if there are links/sources to more information on it? why, in which cases etc.

Comment: @mohican93 there is not really a link follow up. I am guessing you are going through some kind of tutorial or lecture right now? The topic and technique will probably be discussed in that any way. It just is a class, with a private member and a constructor accepting a value for that parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Your result variable is only accessible from within the "stringBits" method. Since the method returns a string you can do the following to print it:

```
System.out.println(stringBits(string)); //Call in main method in place of printString();
```

Edited: My code wasn't a working example. Note that stringBits has to be a static method in order to work.

Comment: Thank you, CConard96! 

I have tried it already, though; stringBits() is said to be not accessible from non static field; then I make String stringBits static, and that`s what I get: stringBits can not be applied to () .

Edited part of code:

public static String stringBits(String str) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i<str.length();i += 1) {
            result += str.substring(i, i+1);
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static void printString () {
        System.out.println(stringBits());
    }
}

Comment: Please edit your original question to add code instead of posting it in a comment. Also, the problem you're getting is because you aren't passing any arguments to `stringBits()`. You need to call `stringBits(str)`. Also, `str`, is currently not accessible to `printString()`, so you also need to pass `str` to this method.